# Find algorithm class

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have homework do find/create algorithm that solves this problem :

- `n` - number of buckets
- `k` - number of different colors of blocks
- `p_i` - capacity of bucket number i
- `c_i` - number of blocks with color i

assumption is that buckets are standing on circumference of a circle.

What is to be done:
every bucket must have at most one block of each color. And basic operation is transfer block to neighbour bucket.

I don't expect solution to this problem, right now I'm wondering which class of problem is this - graph or something else.

Thanks a lot.

Edit : I have to write it in c++.

Edit : Problem example

- 1 bucket capacity 5: 1 yellow 2 green
- 2 bucket capacity 5 :1 white 2 yellow
- 3 bucket capacity 2: 2 blue
- 4 bucket capacity 7: 1 green

Algorithm has to make every bucket includes at most one block of each color.

Edit : my ideas

I was thinking about search tree where i will generate all possibilities of correct placing block, but i'm not sure how to count steps in this solution. Another idea was to "sweep" from every bucket block which shouldn't be inside. Last idea was to look at the problem from block perspective and "sweep" buckets which includes more than one block of every color. But i can't find any strong idea, which will solve this problem.

Edit : my algorithm

1. count how many blocks of each color I have.
2. Sort this descending.
3. For every COLOR starting with the most numerous one :

   1. For every bucket :
           1. If this bucket contains more than 1 block of COLOR go to 2. else continue.
           2. Try to put block of COLOR to neighbour bucket. If any of neighbours don't                                      have enough place, then swap on block from neighbour bucet to this bucket, then put block of COLOR to this neigbour bucket.

Comment: What problem? What should the algorithm do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think the answer will be? Please show us some more effort.

Comment: Your instructor didn't give you any information on algorithms before giving you this assignment?

Comment: At the beginning in every bucket situation is random. For example
 - 1 bucket capacity 5: 1 yellow 2 green
 - 2 bucket capacity 5 :1 white 2 yellow
 - 3 bucket capacity 2: 2 blue
 - 4 bucket capacity 7: 1 green

Algorithm has to find the smallest number of steps to make every bucket at most one block of each color.

Comment: I was thinking about search tree where i will generate all possibilities of correct placing block, but i'm not sure how to count steps in this solution.
Another idea was to "sweep" from every bucket block which shouldn't be inside.
Last idea was to look at the problem from block perspective and "sweep" buckets which includes more than one block of every color.
But i can't find any strong idea, which will solve this problem.

Comment: what do you mean by `basic operation is transfer block to neighbour bucket` - is that the only allowed way to change contents of a bucket?

Comment: Can you choose *which* neighbor bucket, or must all transfers be in the same direction?

Comment: @MichałRybak yes, this is what I mean.
Beta Yes I can choose neighbor bucket.

Comment: Will not `c_i` be always 0 or 1 ? Why do you need it ?

Comment: `c_i` is number of blocks which have color i in all buckets.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I would suggest a [**Doubly-Linked-List**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) data structure. But without knowing what language you'll be writing it in, I don't think anybody can help you further.

For example though, you could create a `Doubly-Linked-List`, and fill it with members of type `myObject`.

In Java, `myObject` would be a `Class`. In C, `myObject` would be a `Struct`, etc.

You want to link these objects so that each one has a reference to *both* its neighbors. Then you can *pass a block* to a 'neighbor' (**linked**) bucket.

Though how you create your data structure(s) is language-dependent for the most part...

**Edit**: In a simple case, you could create an `array` of objects (Java `Class`, C `Struct`, etc), and then give neighbors blocks by using `n - 1` (left) and `n + 1` (right), where `n` is your current bucket in the array.

Comment: what advantages does doubly-linked-list have over simple array in this case? we are given `n`, so our data structure has fixed size.

Comment: You can create an `array` of `n` objects (like a Java `Class` or C-`Struct`) just fine. A *doubly-linked-list* is a bit more complicated to design, but in my experience provides a lot more functionality. It all depends on what you need. However, an `array` is probably more suitable for you considering what you need. In that case, you could create an `array` of objects, and then *give* neighbors blocks by using `n - 1` and `n + 1`, where `n` is your current **bucket** in the array.

Comment: You'll probably prefer `(k + n - 1) mod n` and `(k + 1) mod n` (assuming `k` is the current buffer) to ensure that next element after `nth` will be the first one and element before first will be the `nth`.